# Stripe Create Payment Intents Promise Never Resolves

Tags: reactjs, npm, stripe-payments, strip

I signed up for a Stripe account and followed some simple steps to get up and running with Node. I just installed the package and tested a payment Intents with my test key:

```
const Stripe = require('stripe');

const handleStripe = async () => {
    const stripe = Stripe(testKeyString);
   
    console.log(“we make it here”);

    try {

        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: 1000,
            currency: 'usd',
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            receipt_email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
        });
   
        //we never make it here
        console.log(paymentIntent);
    }
    catch(err){
        //we never make it here either
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

The console logs “we make it here”, but nothing else. The promise is never resolved.

I suspect that this might be a bug with the stripe npm package. Anybody have any thoughts on why the promise is never returned?

EDIT: sorry, I wasted everyone’s time here. I was following the docs QuickStart where it said “install a client library” and I assumed it was for the front end. So a very silly mistake on my part thinking that it was a good idea to make a payment intent from the front end with a secret key. Just getting going with the Stripe API and I’m off to a bad start. Thanks for your comments and answer

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if the try and catch is needed. Try removing it. 
I did it in Python so this is a bit unfamiliar to me.

Comment: The code you posted seems totally fine assuming your test key is good. Have you tried letting it sit for a few minutes? Maybe once the promise times out something useful will print to the console.

Comment: I guess there some problem with your country rules regarding payments (even I faced the same issue), go to your stripe dashboard > payments section then you will find why your payment was not successful

Comment: If there was no problem in stripe dashboard then consider putting up the whole code because I am not sure if you are returning something from your promise or not

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run it without the try/catch?  Also what do you get if you try https://status.stripe.com/reachability from that server - are you sure you can reach Stripe's servers?